# Mount-DiskImage fails with unhelpful error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to mount a Windows 10 install ISO so that I can then use it with DISM to programmatically activate .NET 3.5 because crappy Autodesk software requires ancient dependencies. Rant about Autodesk aside, when I use

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "\\Mac\Archive\OSs\Win10_English_x64.iso" -NoDriveLetter
```

on my test VM, to path to a UNC share, I get this error

```
Mount-DiskImage : The parameter is incorrect. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "\\Mac\Archive\OSs\Win10_English_x64.iso"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Mount-DiskImage
```

usually I get a more useful error out of Powershell, but here I am unsure if the issue is I can't use a UNC path (the example code used a drive letter), or maybe the issue is with the fact that the share is created by Parallels since this is a Mac hosted VM, or perhaps the issue is that the ISO is for an older build of Windows 10 and I have to use a more current ISO? Certainly the path is good, and all the ISOs are valid (I have used them to install Windows on Parallels VMs), and I have tried multiple different ISOs with the same error every time. I am testing in the ISO running elevated. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just copy the ISO locally first. Mount it then remove it once the operation is done. That is a long pending thing in PS which they dont support remote ISO mount.

Comment: @ranadip-dutta Good to know, thanks! In my case I will instead do a one time mount, and copy the Sources folder to the network, as I will need to do the install on hundreds of machines, and copying the entire ISO locally every time will not be efficient. But now I know what my original approach was failing.

Comment: Makes sense since you have 100s. But do a test path and ISO attached validation in if condition while you will be using foreach loop and also do not forget to use try/catch. Else if one system, in between, fails; the loop will stop and rest will not be mounted at all. So do all checks and balances required.